# How to add marker on GoogleMap first screen from an other screen

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps, user-interface, google-maps-markers

I have a main screen with a GoogleMap Widget. I display markers there. When I add a marker from a third screen to the list of markers, the list updates but the GUI does not. The first screen send list to second via routes and then to the third one. When I move map, marker appear. But not when I came back on first screen.

```
class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key, required this.title});

  final String title;

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  late GoogleMapController mapController;
  MarkerList markersList = MarkerList();

  Route _createRouteToSecondScreen(MarkerList markerList) {
    return PageRouteBuilder(
      opaque: false,
      pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => SecondScreen(
        centerMove: LatLng(-33.865143, 151.209900),
        markerList: markerList,
      ),
    );
  }

  Future<void> _onMapCreated(GoogleMapController controller) async {
    mapController = controller;
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: GoogleMap(
        markers: Set<Marker>.of(markersList.markers),
        mapType: MapType.hybrid,
        myLocationButtonEnabled: false,
        myLocationEnabled: true,
        compassEnabled: false,
        onMapCreated: _onMapCreated,
        onCameraMove: (CameraPosition cp) {
          setState(() {});
        },
        initialCameraPosition: const CameraPosition(
          target: LatLng(0, 0), //_center
          zoom: 2,
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Navigator.of(context).push(_createRouteToSecondScreen(markersList));
        },
        child: const Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:test_map/thirdScreen.dart';

import 'markerList.dart';

class SecondScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final LatLng centerMove;
  final MarkerList markerList;

  const SecondScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.centerMove,
    required this.markerList,
  });

  @override
  SecondScreenState createState() => SecondScreenState();
}

class SecondScreenState extends State<SecondScreen> {
  //late MarkerList copyMarkerList;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  Route _createRouteInfo(LatLng latlng, MarkerList markerList) {
    return PageRouteBuilder(
        opaque: false,
        pageBuilder: (context, animation, secondaryAnimation) => ThirdScreen(
              latlng: latlng,
              markersList: markerList,
            ));
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        child: InkWell(
            onTap: () async {
              Navigator.of(context).push(_createRouteInfo(widget.centerMove, widget.markerList));
            },
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 60.0,
                  color: Color(0xff28B39E),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Continue",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),
                ),
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';
import 'package:uuid/uuid.dart';

import 'markerList.dart';

class ThirdScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final LatLng latlng;
  final MarkerList markersList;

  const ThirdScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.latlng,
    required this.markersList,
  });

  @override
  ThirdScreenState createState() => ThirdScreenState();
}

class ThirdScreenState extends State<ThirdScreen> {
  var uuid = Uuid();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(
        child: InkWell(
            onTap: () {
              widget.markersList.addMarker(
                Marker(
                  markerId: MarkerId(uuid.v1().toString()),
                  position: LatLng(widget.latlng.latitude, widget.latlng.longitude),
                ),
              );
              setState(() {});

              int count = 0;
              Navigator.of(context).popUntil((_) => count++ >= 2);
            },
            child: Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                Container(
                  height: 60.0,
                  color: Color(0xff28B39E),
                ),
                Text(
                  "Add marker",
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 18.0),
                ),
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```

Here my markersList class :

```
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

class MarkerList extends ChangeNotifier {
  final Set<Marker> _markers = <Marker>{};

  Set<Marker> get markers => _markers;

  void addMarker(Marker marker) {
    _markers.add(marker);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

I would like to be able to add a marker to the list and especially that it is displayed graphically on the map when I return to the first screen. Without having to move the card, simply after adding.

Answer (score 0):

I find a solution :
In _MyHomePageState I add :

```
FutureOr onGoBack(dynamic value) {
  setState(() {});
}
```

And when route was called :

```
Navigator.of(context).push(_createRouteToSecondScreen(markersList)).then(onGoBack);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).